# Яке значення має слово "сі" у виразі "міжи містом і селом грань вже сі стирає"?

Tags: значення-слів, діалектизми

[Рок-н-рол до рана](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iq68dKypIdI)

> Сидит баба на загаті
> Маєтки латає
> Міжи містом і селом
> Грань **вже сі** стирає

Що тут означає слово "сі"? Підсилювальна частка для слова вже? Я не знайшов її в UKRLIT.ORG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут накладаються два явища:

1. відокремлена частка
2. значення у даному конкретному випадку

#### Відокремлення зворотної частки

Це відокремлена частка *-ся* (*-сі*, *-си*).

Явище відокремлення частки, що позначає [рефлексивні дієслова](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%94%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE) (reflexive verbs) поширене у західних діалектах. На диво, я не знайшов досить лаконічної статті про це явище, але воно згадується, наприклад тут: [Wikipedia: Наддністрянський говір](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%80).

> В українській мові зворотні дієслова мають постфікс *-ся*, що є за походженням короткою формою знахідного відмінка зворотного займенника, що почала зростатися зі своїм дієсловом ще в староукраїнську добу — [Wikipedia](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%94%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE)

Отже

- канонічна форма: *збирати себе* > *збирати* + *-ся* = *збирати**ся***
- діалектні форми: ***ся** збирати*, *він **сі** збирає*, *я **сі** ще учора зібрав* тощо.

#### Цей конкретний приклад

Згідно викладеному вище, значення мало б бути таким:
*Сі стирає* = *стирається*.

Але здається, що у цьому випадку *баба стирає грань між містом і селом*, дієслово «*стирає*» не є рефлексивним.

На мою думку, тут «*сі*» у прямому значенні «*собі*», тобто, баба виконує якусь дію собі на користь.

Ще варто зазначити, що пісня жартівлива, тому можливо, автори просто використали "вже сі" (без якого цілком можна обійтися) для заповнення прогалин у розмірі вірша (так само, як «*міжи*» використано замість більш поширеного «*між*»).

Comment: Дякую! Ще я знайшов таку цікаву сторінку у російській Вікіпедії: [ся (энклитика)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%8F_(%D1%8D%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0))